# Making perl modules executable

Tags: perl, executable

I am new to Perl. I have created a Perl module(.pm). I am trying to make it executable. I wanna know is it possible to make Perl module executable or I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Or, in other words: why do you want to make a a Perl module a "binary file" (whatever that means)?

Comment: @Dada I want to make perl file to behave like a binary file which gets create after executing c file

Comment: Compiling Perl code into machine instructions isn't a goal anyone ever has. What is [the problem are you actually trying to solve](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)?

Comment: so reading the comments to the answer, it seems the actual problem was "distributing perl code without allowing the recipient to be able to read the code"

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to compile Perl code into machine instructions? There is no such tool. While Perl is compiled, it's compiled into high-level opcodes which require an interpreter to evaluate.

Comment: I want to make perl file to behave like a binary file which gets create after executing c file

Comment: One doesn't execute C files. /// "Binary file" is meaningless. It's just a catch-all term used for files that aren't human-readable. /// "To behave like a binary file" makes no sense. Files don't do anything, so nothing behaves like a file. /// I still think you are asking how to compile Perl code into machine instructions.

Comment: exactly, I want to make it human-unreadable. Is it possible with perl files?

Comment: It's very easy to make a file that isn't readable by humans. You could compress it, encrypt it, replace it with garbage, etc. Again I ask: What is the problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: okay, I'll try this. Thank you so much for your efforts.

Comment: There is no non-reversible way to obfuscate Perl source code while still allowing it to work, since the Perl interpreter ultimately needs the original Perl source code. So whatever you do must be reversible by the Perl interpreter and thus can be reversed by anyone else (barring a shared-key encryption).